# Handle redirects using Okhttp in Android

Tags: android, http, redirect, okhttp

I make some **http requests using Okhttp to download a JSON** from my server.
For me and all my alpha testers everything works fine, but out in the wild I 
experience some exceptions that occur, when I try to parse the response using 
Gson.

As far as I understand the **exceptions occur, because the connection gets redirected**, in situations where the user is at an airport or using a limited
WIFI connection in an hotel etc.

The exception:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read (Http1xStream.java:378)
okio.Buffer.writeAll (Buffer.java:956)
okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray (RealBufferedSource.java:92)
okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes (ResponseBody.java:83)
okhttp3.ResponseBody.string (ResponseBody.java:109)
[xxxx].BackendFilter.handleResponse (BackendFilter.java:131)
[xxxx].BackendFilter.access$300 (BackendFilter.java:30)
[xxxx].BackendFilter$2.onResponse (BackendFilter.java:114)
okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:133)
okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:32)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

From my logs  in firebase I can see that **the URL of the response is different
to the URL I used to set in the request**.

i.e. I get: http://www.tunisietelecom.tn/tt/themes/html/TT_Theme/infosolde.html

It basically says:

> Dear Customer,
>
> Your plan is exhausted, to continue to benefit from your INTERNET
>   offer, dial * 140 # for packages via your phone or * 145 # for Data
>   key packages.

So I assume this specific user got redirected, because his data package 
got expired.

**The response code nevertheless is a 200** and my application tries to parse
the response body, which fails obviously. Not with the excepetion I 
expected, but it fails anyhow. **(Can anybody explain to me, why this excepetion
occurs. rather than a Gson `JsonSyntaxException`?)**

I read multiple articles on stackoverflow and did a google search beforehand,
but can anybody tell me **how to handle this kind of redirects? 
What is the best approach to smoothly dismiss this request, if I (how?) 
recognize a redirect.**

**tl;dr**

My approach now would be to disable redirects in the first place by setting `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().followRedirects(false).followSslRedirects(false).build();`, but I am not sure (and familar with this topic), if there are 
situations where redirects are total fine and I want to allow them.

The next approach, without disabling redirects would be to investigate the 
response. If the method `response.isRedirect()` returns true and the 
url of the request (`response.request.url()`) is any different from
my requested url, I would smoothly dismiss the request. 
Is any of these approaches suitable? Are there better strategies to handle
these kind of redirects? Does the exception really occur because of a
redirect?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: No idea? Nobody? What can I do to improve my question for you?